# Which registers for OV7670 for returing unsigned 8 byte data instead of 16 bytes data

Tags: camera

In OV7670 you can specify CIF(352x288), QVGA(320x240), QCIF(176x144) and VGA(640x480).

But I'm looking for a minimal resolution. For example QVGA would or QCIF would be a good choie. But here is the problem.

When I select for example no color and QVGA, I send the command `0x12, 0x8`.
But does I get 8-bit data in the length `320*240` or does I get 16-bit gray scaled data?

[image]

Comment: how exactly do you select no color? (rather, monochrome). You mean bit 1 in COM7?

Comment: On datasheet page 1 in the table on the right it lists "Output Format (8-bit): YUV/YCbCr 4:2:2 • RGB565/555 • GRB 4:2:2 • Raw RGB Data ", there is nothing anywhere about greyscale (or other output formats)

Comment: @Ilya Yes, but that means the camera sends 8 bits at the time. Take a look at page 9

Comment: I still don't see anywhere any mention of greyscale